# Possible to DIY a multiple fixture canopy?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, code-compliance

I've been looking at making a fixture for my island that would consist of 5 separate LED bulbs hanging down from a single canopy, each about 15" apart.

Looking at what's out there in terms of commercially made canopies, it's very expensive once you get into the larger items.   A 5' long canopy would be $500-$1000 without any lights involved yet.

Obviously, one solution is track lighting, but that has a rather particular look to it.

When I looked up the various DIY approaches folks have used, none of them seemed to be remotely code-compliant.   I'm not talking about strain relief, but rather wiring done either in open air behind a piece of wood, or wiring done inside a stained pine box with no means of spark protection.

So my thought is that perhaps I could approach it much like when I put wiring into a built in bookcase - I use shallow j-boxes and make sure there is space for everything.  What would be an issue if I built a nice box out of wood, made all the connections in j boxes, and then ran the power to the light through a bushing?   The main problem I would imagine is that I still need to pigtail to the original j-box to get power.

Any other ways to approach this?

Comment: Keep in mind the rules are somewhat relaxed for lighting powered by 12 volts DC, which is perfectly possible with LEDs.  That may be what you are seeing that looks so bad.

Comment: Where are you on the planet?

Comment: I'm in the US.  So I would think NEC is the governing rules around what I need to do.

Comment: @Harper.  No these were all using incandescent bulbs.  So drawing a fair amount of wattage.

Comment: A lot of home-hacked work is done illegally.   Have you looked at low voltage lighting systems like Ikea's?  Read the instructions carefully and see what they allow. NEC requires you follow the instructions when installing lighting, because those are the conditions under which the lights were tested and listed.   If you are doing so, you should be in the clear.

Comment: I have looked at them.  I have a couple Ikea fixtures I've installed in my place.   The low voltage lets you get around a couple challenges, but what I'm looking to do (g25 style mirrored globes hung in sockets w/ covers),I don't know of a way to go 'low voltage' before the bulb.  If I could do that, I'd probably have a few more options in terms of how I locate the splices between each bulb and the main power feed.